# What does "instead" mean as in "to instead do something"?

Tags: word-meaning

[source](http://www.xinhuanet.com//english/2017-08/30/c_136568699.htm)

> Nowadays Chinese entrepreneurs are encouraged to **instead** invest in
>   more sophisticated sectors where they hold a comparative advantage.

I'm struggling with "to instead do something".

It means

> Chinese entrepreneurs are encouraged to **invest** in more
>   sophisticated sectors

or

> Chinese entrepreneurs are encouraged **not** to invest in more
>   sophisticated sectors

?

Another example

> The federal official tapped by an outgoing Obama appointee to lead the
>   Consumer Financial Protection Agency filed a lawsuit on Sunday
>   challenging President Trump’s decision to **instead** appoint his budget
>   director to the post – setting up a Monday showdown at the
>   controversial agency.

I don't know Trump's decision is to appoint his budget director or appoint other people to replace his budget director

Answer (score 1):

The context of the sentence is missing, so a more complete answer is not possible (yet).

However, the meaning is clear:

> Nowadays Chinese entrepreneurs are encouraged to **invest** in more sophisticated sectors where they hold a comparative advantage **instead of** *[doing something else]*.

Answer (score 1):

A phrase like "to instead do X" means "to do X, instead of doing some other thing Y", where you have to understand from context what Y is.  So they substituted X for Y.  They did do X, and they did not do Y.

Saying "to instead do X" is really just like saying "to do X", but adds more information.  It tells you that they are doing X, with the extra information that there was another option that they decided not to do.

(By the way, a phrase like *to instead invest* is a [split infinitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_infinitive) which some people don't like to use.)

virolino has the correct interpretation for your first example.  For the second one:

> The federal official tapped by an outgoing Obama appointee to lead the Consumer Financial Protection Agency filed a lawsuit on Sunday challenging President Trump’s decision to instead appoint his budget director to the post

*The federal official* (whose name was Leandra English) was originally selected to lead the agency.  But President Trump decided not to let her do so.  He appointed *his budget director* (Mick Mulvaney) to replace her.